# problem in computing cycles of permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose we have disjoint cycles $\sigma=(1 3 2 4)(5 6)$ and $\tau=(1 4)(2 5 3 6)$. Can we find some $\alpha\in S_6$ such that $\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1}=\tau$?

My solution:  $\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1}=(\alpha(1) \alpha(3) \alpha(2) \alpha(4))(\alpha(5) \alpha(6))=(2 5 3 6)(1 4)$, and I get$\alpha=(1 2 3 5)(4 6)$. But by checking with a calculator online, my answer is wrong. Can someone help me on identifying where I am wrong and write out the solution? Thank you.

Comment: In which direction do you compose permutations?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. I don't understand what you mean. Can you write your comments to my solution?

Comment: "*by checking with a calculator online*" It is worth pointing out that as Wuestenfux alludes to that different authors use different conventions in regards to the order of applying permutations.  Recall that $\sigma\circ \tau$ might be unequal to $\tau\circ\sigma$.  It is possible that whatever book you are using multiplies permutations in the one direction while the calculator you used multiplies in the other direction.

Comment: I see. From right to left.

Comment: Okay. But can you help me identify whether my method is correct or not?

Comment: The calculator is Wolframalpha. Just type in the command "permutation" and cycles of permutation you'd like to calculate.  https://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: @PseudodifferentialOperators and wolfram applies things left to right.  [$(1~2)(1~3)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=perm+%281+2%29%281+3%29) results in $(1~2~3)$, the opposite of what I interpret you as saying the convention you follow is.  Note the fine print, "*the product $\sigma \tau$ represents the permutation $\tau(\sigma(\cdot))$*"

Comment: Oh, I see. I checked by wolfram alpha again by correct order. It is correct. Thanks everyone!

Comment: From what we can tell, yes.  If you were to just reverse the order in which you write the permutations (*with a tad bit of laziness allowed in terms of disjoint cycles*) in order to account for the differences in order in which permutations are applied between your convention and wolfram's, you can get [wolfram to agree](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=perm+%281+2+3+5%29%5E-1%284+6%29%281+3+2+4%29%285+6%29%281+2+3+5%29%284+6%29)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composition of permutations left to right or right to left?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527514/composition-of-permutations-left-to-right-or-right-to-left)

Comment: Actually, I just figured it out by myself. Anyway, thanks for answering!

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394423/conjugacy-in-s-n-with-composing-permutations-left-to-right-vs-right-to-left?rq=1